# Inserting empty array with loop

Tags: swift

I want to add value to an empty array by looping another array's value

```
var Person : [String:String]

var data : [String:String] = [
   "name" : "John",
    "age"   : "22"
]

for (index, value) in data {
    Person[index] = value
}
```

And I got this error "variable Person passed by reference before being initialized"

Why is that?

Comment: Why is this question tagged obj-c and obj-c++?

Comment: in swift you have initialize your variables or mark them as optional

Comment: @angger have you try my ans?

Comment: @Vvk i just try to explain swift variable declaration logic instead of direct answer it.

Comment: @AliKıran Thanks for explaination :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
// Array initialization
    var Person = [String:String]()

    var data : [String:String] = [
        "name" : "John",
        "age"   : "22"
    ]

    for (index, value) in data {
        Person[index] = value
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you ! I guess I'm being reckless there

Comment: @Angger welcome. There are many ways to initialize array but this one is simple.

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
var Person : [String:String]
```

to:

```
var Person = [String:String]()
```

to initialise the array before using it.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective C

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
  NSMutableArray *arr,*arrSecond;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   //First Array
   arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"iOS",@"Android",@"Windows",@"Blackberry",@"Symbion",@"Bada",nil];
   arrSecond = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   for(int i=0;i<[arr count];i++)
   {
     //Second Array inside the for loop.It is getting objects from First loop of for
     [arrSecond addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are declaring here is a dictionary, not an array. The same result that is being achieved by the above code (in the answer from Vvk) could be achieved by simply writing:

```
var Person = [ "name" : "John", "age" : "22" ]
```

If you want to use a loop to add items to a dictionary then you could, but I don't see the value of it in this context.

If the aim is to set values in `Person` equal to the values in `data` then you can just write:

```
var Person = [String:String]()

var data = [ "name" : "John", "age"   : "22" ]

Person = data
```

No need for  a loop, unless the wider scope of your project requires it.